# Google analytics API gave different results

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api

we have some request to GA API:

```
$this->service->data_ga->get(
    self::GA_IDS, 
    $this->start_date, 
    $this->end_date, 
    'ga:users',
    array(
        'dimensions'    => 'ga:mobileDeviceBranding,ga:city,ga:dimension1,ga:date', 
        'sort'          => 'ga:date',
        'start-index'   => $this->start_index,
        'max-results'   => self::CNT_PER_PAGE
    )
)
```

After we insert data to database.
After we take sum the 5th column of the response (value of users metric) from the DB.
We run the request in different days (truncating the table) and accept different users sum.
The question, is it possible, that running the request in different times we will receive different result? Or it can be just bug in the code?
We use  google/apiclient:^2.0.0.